# DOS Batch script to iterate through NTFS drives

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ntfs

I need a Batch FOR loop that iterates through the driveletters of NTFS drives only.

I found a way to do a FOR loop like so:

```
for %%X in (C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\) do <bla>
```

Obviously I could go A-Z to get all drives, however, how can I enforce that it only goes through NTFS drives and not FAT32, CDFS, etc.?

Can I build in a check somehow or generate the array of driveletters beforehand?

Yes, it has to be Windows Batch DOS, so no powershell, vbscript or other languages please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f %%A in ('wmic logicaldisk where "FileSystem='NTFS'" get name') do ...
```

Note that the values in `%%A` will not include the backslash. They will look like `C:`, `D:`, etc.